# Forgot git rebase --continue

Tags: git

I was on my own local feature branch and wanted to merge it into master. I checked out master, did `git pull --rebase`, had one conflict, resolved it, but I forgot to do `git rebase --continue` after that. Then I did `git merge my_other_branch` and then wanted to push that to origin, but git told me im not on any branch, so I was like "oh no, i fogot `rebase --continue`" so I did it then and git says "no changes - did you forget to use git add?". So right now I'm not on any branch...in some detached head state.

What do I need to do to get back on track?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git rebase --skip
```

Should continue the rebase.

Comment: Or you can do `git rebase --abort` and do it all over again.

Comment: @yasouser Yeah, that might very well be the best course. But I believe that would throw away the merge.

Comment: Yes, it will throw away the merge. I suggested it just as another option to start fresh from the previous good state of the repo.

Comment: @KlasMellbourn so this would keep the merge of my_other_branch into master but restart the botched rebase?

Answer (score 1):

Klas's answer is probably more useful, but in general a "detached head" means that where you're looking isn't a branch.

Thus, you can solve this by checking out a branch (specifically, the branch you wish you were on).

If something like this happens again, I would suggest looking at your current status with `gitk --all`, to get an idea about the repository structure and where you are.

Answer (score 0):

That is a difficult question, because you now messed with the internals of `rebase`. I would recommend these steps:

- Start `gitk --all` to see your current structure. You should especially be able to see your current HEAD and your previous branchhead. Look at the commits on HEAD and see which of them are useful. Create a temp-branch on your current HEAD if you think you will still need it later. Maybe commit your current state first with `git commit -am "dirty"`
- Run `git rebase --abort` – you messed up this rebase. I don’t think the rebase script will be able to get you out of there.
- You should now be back at your old branch-head
- Get back all the commits you want to get back, using `git rebase --onto` and `git  cherry-pick`. Fix up further with `git reset`, `git commit --ammend` and `git rebase`.

  - For example: If your branch contains commits `A--B--C`, and you successfully rebased `A` and `B` to `A'` and `B'` (check in gitk), you could `rebase --onto B' B`.